# Solve for variable with a constraint?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have this equation:

$3x+1 = \frac{x}{2^a}$

And I'm trying to solve for $a$ such that the expression of $a$ does not contain an $x$ in it.

No matter how much I try I can't isolate the $x$ and $a$...

Does anyone know a way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "the expression of a does not contain an x in it", how about that ? 3x+1 = x/2^a => 2^a(3x+1)=x => 2^a = x/(3x+1) => log_2 2^a = log_2 (x/(3x+1)) => a = log_2(x/(3x+1))

Comment: For example, if I try to solve for $a$, it will end up being a $log$ of like $x/(3x+1)$, this has $x$'s in it which I am trying to avoid...

Comment: when we "solve for something" doesn't it mean to write everything else in terms of it ? (including x in this case)

Comment: This is not an [tag:abstract-algebra] question, rather, an [tag:algebra-precalculus] one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
3x+1=\frac{x}{2^a} & \iff \frac1{3x+1}=\frac{2^a}x \\
& \iff 2^a=\frac{x}{3x+1} \\
& \iff \log_2(2^a)=\log_2\left[\frac{x}{3x+1}\right] \\ 
& \iff a=\log_2\left[\frac{x}{3x+1}\right] \,\checkmark
\end{align}$$

I hope this helps.
Best wishes, $\mathcal H$akim.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot get rid of $x$, since $a$ depends on $x$. For different values of $x$ you get different values of $a$. You have

$$ a = \log_2{\frac{x}{3x+1}} $$